# SSIS Excel Source Metadata

Tags: excel, ssis

I have Excel source with these data:

```
Code
5.43_P
5.43_P
5.43_P
5.43_P
5,31
5,31
5,31
5,31
```

Now I want to load those data into table which has the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE X(
Code nvarchar(10) null
)
```

When I load the data from the Excel to this table destination (there are no transformation between the source and destination), the values "5.43_P" do not insert into table.

When I check the metadata for the `Code` column from Excel source, it has data type `DT_R8` (float).

What are my options now how to fix this? Can I change the metadata of the Excel source column so it loads all data into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Add parameter "IMEX=1" into the Excel connection string, see [link](http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/15/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/).